# Wget on my mac doesn't let me do recursive

Tags: mac, wget

I'm on a mac running 10.8, upgraded over time from 10.6. I have wget which I've been using for a while for single files however attempted to do an old command from the linux days to do a recursive download, ie:

```
wget -r http://site.com/folder/
```

This brought up an error I haven't seen before:

```
Warning: Invalid character is found in given range. A specified range MUST 
Warning: have only digits in 'start'-'stop'. The server's response to this 
Warning: request is uncertain.
curl: no URL specified!
```

I looked at the wget --help and couldn't find any mention of recursive downloading.

Whats wrong with my wget, or my command?

Comment: Where did you install `wget` from? Which version do you have? What is the *exact* command you're using? And why would `wget` spit out an error message from `curl`?

Comment: I didn't install it - actually it came 'installed' but actually I just realised that the exact same help information is displayed for curl - in otherwords, apple have made wget simply point to curl - lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `wget` is actually a link to `curl` (or a renamed copy or an alias). Someone must have thought this was a good idea.

Curls  `-r` option is different

```
-r, --range <range>
```

Either learn `curl` or delete the link/copy/alias and install the real `wget`, for example [through Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with `brew install wget`.